# AES Decryption - Expand Key/First Roundkey

Tags: aes, decryption

I am wondering how to use and expand keys  during the Decryption.

Let’s say we have an initial key (128bits): 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 6A 6B 6C 6D 6E 6F 70

So we get:  w[0] = (61 62 63 64), w[1]=( 65 66 67 68),w[2]=( 69 6A 6B 6C),w[3]( 6D 6E 6F 70)

Then with the g () function, we get:

- Circular byte left shift of w[3] = 6E 6F 70 6D
- Byte substitution using the  SBOX
- Adding round constant for the round (for round 1 = 01 00 00 00)

To get the first round key we then perform : **w[4] = w[0] ⊕ g(w[3])**, **w[5] = w[4] ⊕ w[1]** , **w[6] = w[5] ⊕ w[2]**, **w[7] = w[6] ⊕ w[3]**.

We repeat the process for all rounds. For 10 rounds will generate 10 subkeys + the initial key.

During the encryption process, each subkey will be used in the corresponding Add round key function.

For the  Decryption process, do we have to perform a similar operation but, i.e using inverse S-Box?, or do we just generate the subkeys and then use the subkeys in the corresponding round?

Thanks

Comment: Generate the same subkeys, but use them in reverse order

Comment: I see, so when it said that the decryption algorithm uses the same subkeys used in the encryption algorithm, it is meant that it uses the same subkeys because generated by the same initial key. So will the initial key be used only for generating subkeys, for encrypting the State in the Initial Add round key and for decrypting the State in the last Add round key? Also, does the Expand key process can be considered part of the encryption/decryption process or something apart?  Thanks

Comment: Your statement about initial key is sort of true for AES-128, but not for AES-196 or AES-256 where the initial key forms part of the first round key as well as the Initial Add. Terminology opinions will vary as to whether the Expand Key process is part of the encryption/decryption process, but I would consider it so, particularly as there are implementations that interleave the processes to generate subkeys "one the fly".

Comment: I see, thent the main key (or part of it) is actually used only in the first and last round, Where can I found description of  AES-192 or AES-256 transformation processes ?